# Strange fglrx slow down under Debian

Tags: linux, graphics-card, debian, amd-radeon, fglrx

I am getting a weird slowdown on all non-OpenGL applications while running some OpenGL applications such as Chromium (while playing a YouTube video), Steam and Blender. Games are running perfectly fine, I really don't know what's causing that issue.

Here's a video describing what's happening : http://youtu.be/uuVIgEpBvvM

I'm using a MSI laptop with

- Memory : 6GB DDR3
- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
- Graphics card : ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870
- glxinfo dump : http://pastebin.com/rR5EqqUL
- Distribution : Debian Wheezy upgraded with Jessie repositories
- Window Manager : Awesome

For the Cataclyst settings, it behaves exactly the same way when I enable or disable Cataclyst A.I., same thing for the Vertical Refresh.

My xorg.conf is the following :

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option  "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Did I miss something ? What's the exact word to describe that kind of issue ?